# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } Var(Y_{n}) = 0$.

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Given $Var(Y_{n}) = (\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})^2\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}$.

My work: $$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } Var(Y_{n}) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } (\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})^2\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{(\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})^2}{(1 + \frac{2}{n}) (n+1)^{2}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{\frac{(\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})^2}{n^2}}{(1 + \frac{2}{n}) (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{2}} = 0.$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } (\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})^2\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2} = (\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})^2\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2} $

However, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}=0$  (Do you know why?).

**ADDED part:**

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}=$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{(1+\frac2n)(n+1)^2}=$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=0$

Comment: No, I don't why. Could you please explain?

Comment: See the added part.